# Cannot find module 'destroy'

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, npm, yo

I am using "yo angular-fullstac" and getting below error when running "grunt server" or "grunt serve --force" command. Any idea why this happens? How to fix it?

```
Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task
File .tmp/app/app.css created.
File .tmp/app/app.css.map created (source map).

Running "express:dev" (express) task
Starting background Express server
Debugger listening on port 5858
module.js:338
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'destroy'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\NEWMM\node_modules\express\node_modules\s
end\index.js:8:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)

Running "wait" task
>> Waiting for server reload...
Done waiting!

Running "open:server" (open) task

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

Comment: Install destroy with npm i destroy -S and try again.  What's the result?

Comment: Thanks its working now :)